# useReducer for shopping cart without the use of context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm kinda new to React and JS in general please excuse the messy code. I'm currently trying to make a shopping cart with React hooks useReducer but in the future if I just add more case it might become hard to handle bug.
I tried the useContext but it seems like I have to rewrite most of the code and I'm only using it in 1 page so I don't think it's that necessary.

My reducer file

```
const initCart = [];
export const ACTION = {
  ADD_TO_CART: 'add_to_cart',
  REMOVE_FROM_CART: 'remove_from_cart',
  INCREMENT: 'increment',
  DECREMENT: 'decrement',
};

function CartReducer(state, action) {
  const newState = [...state];
  const productIndex = newState.findIndex((val) => val.id == action.payload.id);

  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION.ADD_TO_CART:
      if (productIndex < 0) {
        newState.push(action.payload);
      } else newState[productIndex].quantity++;
      return newState;
    case ACTION.INCREMENT:
      newState[action.payload.idx].quantity++;

      return newState;
    case ACTION.DECREMENT:
      if (newState[action.payload.idx].quantity > 1) newState[action.payload.idx].quantity--;
      else return newState.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
      return newState;
    case ACTION.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return newState.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return;
  }
}
const Store = () => {
  const [cart, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, initCart);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const Total = () => {
    let total = 0;
    cart.map((item) => (total += item.price * item.quantity));

    return total;
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="d-flex flex-row">
        <ItemList dispatch={dispatch} />
        <SearchBar onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
        <div>
          {cart && <div>Total value {Total()}</div>}
          <p>Cart Detail:</p>
          {cart && cart.filter(val=> val.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())).map((item, idx) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id}>
                  <button
                    onClick={() =>
                      dispatch({
                        type: ACTION.INCREMENT,
                        payload: {
                          idx: idx,
                          id: item.id,
                        },
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    Add
                  </button>
                  <p>Item: {item.name}</p>
                  <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                  <p>Quantity:{item.quantity}</p>
                  <button
                    onClick={() =>
                      dispatch({ type: ACTION.DECREMENT, payload: { idx: idx, id: item.id } })
                    }
                  >
                    Subtract
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTION.REMOVE_FROM_CART, payload: item.id })}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My item list:

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Fruit', price: 69000},
  { id: 2, name: 'Veggies', price: 81000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Meat', price: 130000 },
];

export const ItemList = ({ dispatch }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column" key={item.id}>
          <div>Name: {item.name}</div>
          <div>Price: {item.price}</div>
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={()=>dispatch({
                type: ACTION.ADD_TO_CART,
                payload: {
                  id: item.id,
                  name: item.name,
                  price: item.price,
                  quantity: 1,
                },
              })}
            >
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code work like intended but I would like to make it easier to read. So my question is which is the easiest way to extract the logic and the action payload inside the reducer switch statement outside reducer function so what is left inside each case mostly will be like

```
case ACTION.INCREMENT:
      return addToCart()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
case ACTION.INCREMENT:
      return addToCart()
```

is not something you would want to do as long as you follow the style guide suggested by Redux maintainers. You are not directly using Redux, but you are actually using a hook inspired by "reducer concept" of Redux and the reducers are pure functions which can be tested easily. They are pure because they take one value and spits out another one without modifying it (This is why you clone the `state` into `newState` in your `CartReducer` actually.) or causing any other side effects. For these reasons, you try to put as much as logic inside them just like they suggest [here](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers).

What I would recommend to you is, not naming variables like `newState` while writing React/Redux related code and naming them according to what they really mean in your app's logic for better understandability. (`newState` is actually the `products` or `items` in your next lifecycle.) Otherwise you would have a `newState` in each one of your reducers and the code where you extract a data slice used around the app would not indicate what that data really is. Because reducers are where you will be looking at to understand what happened to that data and it won't be hard to debug as long as you obey the rules of React/Redux code.